# Problem R: Stationary Distribution of a Markov Chain using Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: r, distribution, montecarlo, markov-chains

Using Monte Carlo simulation, estimate the limiting distribution that is a stationary distribution of the Markov chain with two possible initial states:

a)X0 = 1

b)X0 = 2

```
#transition matrix
 P = matrix(c(.5, 0, .5, 0, .5, .5, 0, 0, .3), nrow = 3, ncol = 3,
               byrow = TRUE)
# msim_cadena.markov is a created function that is composed by:
# m is number of chains to simulate
# number of transitions
#initial state     
 msim_cadena.markov<- function(m, num_trans, x0, P){
 P_n<- matrix(0,m,(num_trans+1))
 for(i in 1:m){
 P_n[i,]<- sim1_cadena.markov(num_trans, x0, P)
   }
  estados<- numeric(num_trans+1)
  for(i in 0:num_trans) estados[i+1]<- paste('step',i)
  colnames(P_n)<- estados
  P_n
 }
#stationary distribution
# runs are number of simulations
 stat_distr<-function(runs, num_trans)
 x0_1<- x0_1<- t(msim_cadena.markov(num_sims, num_trans, 1, P))
 x0_1<- as.data.frame(x0_1)
 initial.state_1<-length/num_trans
 # I am not sure length of what
```

Stationary distribution is the percentage of transitions are in each state, starting in 1 or 2; so I would have a matrix or vector and it divided by number of transitions.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. Also, could you provide the library or code containing the `sim1_cadena.markov` and `sim_cadena.markov` functions?

Comment: The transition matrix you've given does not appear to be valid. A valid Markov transition matrix must have sums of row entries equal to 1, since the interpretation of a_{i, j} is the probability of transitioning from state i to state j (and the total of those probabilities across j must be 1). Rows 1 and 2 are fine, but row 3 only has a single nonzero entry of 0.3. If you want to edit the question, please feel free to tag me in the reply and I'll take another look at it.